# How to apply where-criteria to the same field more than once in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

I want to express this query in TypeORM:

```
select * from user where x > 5 and x < 10
```

or other variations, like:

```
select * from user where x > '2020-01-01' and x < '2020-10-10'
select * from user where x >= 5.5 and x <> 10
```

How do I do it?

```
userRepo.find({where: {x: MoreThan(5), x: LessThan(10)}})
```

is obviously not legal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Basic

On [find-options page](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options) there is a between function that lets you just do that

```
import {Between} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    likes: Between(1, 10)
});
```

So in your case its:

```
userRepo.find({where: {x: Between(5,10)}})
```

---

#### Advanced

If you need more control over the query, as in your appended example, you can use `raw`

```
import {Raw} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    currentDate: Raw(alias =>`${alias} > NOW()`)
});
```

Creates:

```
SELECT * FROM "post" WHERE "currentDate" > NOW()
```

Translated to your problem:

```
userRepo.find({
    where: {
        x: Raw(alias => `${alias} >= 5.5 and ${alias} <> 10`) 
    }
})
```

---

#### Custom

This might become too tedious fast and you might want to resort to the more basic [query builder](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder) for more control

Comment: That matches less than or equal and greater than or equal, not less than and greater than though. It's not exactly the same. On my original query, I'm working with dates, so, it's not as simple of adding or subtracting 1.

Comment: I corrected the question to avoid matching one and only one single narrow case, since what I'm after is learning and understanding how to use TypeORM.